Which is correct? "The situation is in favor of me" or "mine"?
Which sentence is correct?  And why?

The situation is in favor of me
The situation is in favor of mine


Neither, both are wrong. The situation is in my favor. And you need to show some effort of your own when you ask questions.

@Faisal. "me" is correct, but as FF says in their answer, we would more naturally say "in my favor".

Please edit to tell a bit more about the context, and about why you thought of these choices or what concerns you have. That will let us give better answers than "both are bad."

It was my feelings, I was sharing in my social media platform. That Fortune should favor me. In this way I got confuse, was i written something that grammaticality not appropriate. But it expressed my true feelings.


1: in favor of me
2: in favor of John

...are both syntactically valid. But idiomatically, native Anghlophones almost always prefer the possessive pronoun and Saxon Genitive forms...

3: in my favor
4:  in John's favor


(I tolerate favor out of respect for the OP, but obviously I'd prefer favour! :)
